# Have JS-code created in the console persist between page reloads?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I have some code which I defined in the Chrome developer tools console:

```
alert("I was just reloaded");
```

How can I have this code run everytime I reload the browser?

The code is only defined in the console, in Google Chrome in this particular case.

**Note**, I don't want just the log to persist, I want the code to persist and to rerun everytime I reload the page.

Comment: You can't, but you could use  userscripts to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Care to explain what userscripts are? A browser extension to run my own code?

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts might help.

Comment: what's the point of this anyway? this would only affect the single machine that the script was defined on.

Comment: @FelixKling, if you write up an answer regarding your userscripts suggestion I can mark it as solved because it did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this doesn't answer the question *exactly* but achievies similiar results.

**Solution**: Code can't persist between page reloads in the console. Only the console log can persist. However, if you want code to run each time you reload the page, we can use **User scripts**: Which basically is your own Javascript code, stored in a browser extension.

So what you have to do is to download the appropriate User Script extension for your browser. Most common are GreaseMonkey for Firefox. A tutorial can be found here: http://hayageek.com/greasemonkey-tutorial/

With this extension you can then create your own JS code to run on specific (or all) web sites, which will then persist between page reloads, which achieved exactly what I asked for.